# How can I search only for issues in github repository through github rest api?

Tags: rest, github, github-api

I want to get only issues and not pull requests from GitHub rest api in a specific repository, but `https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues` endpoint returns both issues and pull requests. Github rest api docs don't say anything about searching in a specific repository. Adding q parameter to the above method does not do anything. I can't filter response to find only issues because my repository contains much more pull requests than issues.
What is the way to get only issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [search issues/PR API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-issues-and-pull-requests) and filter with your repo path and `is:issue` :

```
GET https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:issue%20repo:owner/repo
```

[For example](https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:issue%20repo:bertrandmartel/aws-admin)

Note that `type:issue` also works, [checkout this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-only-issues-or-pull-requests)

Answer (score 0):

The more compact option would be (March 2022) to use [`gh` 2.7.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.7.0), and it new command [`gh search issues`](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/5334)

> Adds the `search issues` and `search prs` command.
>
> The `search issues` command includes a `--include-prs` flag that allows for including pull requests in the search results.
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7969779/159436553-7ff52845-7c89-42f6-9b5b-588d7c44e4e9.png -- Screen Shot 2022-03-22 at 10 13 15 AM]